# JHipster: React option is not available

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, yarnpkg, yo

This question is about usage of jhipster-generator.

This is written in the documentation (https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/) that it is possible to use React as a frontend framework.

But when I run 'yo jhipster' after installation I see no 'React' option (see picture).
[image: example of the generator run]

What should I do to generate application with Reacto support in JHipster?